# Creating a formula field

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

I have a picklist field with following values:
1)fall 2019
2)Winter 2019
3)summer 2018

I have one more formula filed in the same object. If an user selects Fall 2019 from the picklist , the formula field should return 8193. 
8 - default for all cases
19 - year
3 - value for fall(in the same manner 2 is value for winter and 4 is value for summer).

Please help me to write a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your formula would be:

`IF (NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Picklist__c))), "8" & RIGHT(TEXT(Picklist__c), 2) & 
    CASE(LEFT(TEXT(Picklist__c),Find(" ", TEXT(Picklist__c))-1), 
        "Fall", "3", 
        "Winter", "2", 
        "Summer", "4", 
        "")
, "")`

Change `Picklist__c` with your Pick List field api name.